# Rails Associations and Creating New Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting overwhelmed how to implement this database structure then how to create new records.

Let's say I have a website that stores house for sale listings from different sites.

I have 3 models: House, Listing, Site

- A House has many Listings
- A Listing has a Site and a House
- A Site has many Listings

I created a join table for Houses and Listings. And the same for Listings and Sites.

**Listings model:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :houses
belongs_to :site
```

**Site model:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
```

**House model:**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
```

Is this correct so far?

How do I go about creating new records?

```
site = Site.create({name: 'Test Site'})
house = House.create({price: '100000', address: '123 sesame st'})
```

How to join the listing though?

Comment: `Listing.create(house_id: house.id, site_id: site.id)`, did you try something like that?

Comment: Okay, that's way too easy. As I said I overwhelmed myself. Thanks